# Direct proof of two equivalent definitions of a Krull ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, valuation-theory

Wikipedia gives [a first definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring) of Krull rings, based on prime ideals of minimum height, while the Encyclopedia of Mathematics gives [a second definition](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Krull_ring) based on valuations.

Is there a direct (and hopefully simple) proof of the equivalence of the two definitions, not based on the theory of divisorial ideals?